# Multiple Login Forms On One Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, authentication

Below I have code that is working perfectly, as a single login form. However I need 20 of these on one page and thusfar can not even get a second login form to work. The route I have been going down is simply duplicating both the html and the javascript for each new login form on the page and just changing the i.d's using a number 1...2...3 etc. Can anybody tell me why I can not get more than one login form to work on the page at any one time?

The main reason for this is I do not know how to do one login form that directs to 20 different pages. So thought this might be easier.

HTML

```
<input type="text" value=" Username" id="login" style="color:#888; border-radius: 25px;" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" required>
<input type="text" value=" Password" id="password" style="color:#888; border-radius: 25px;" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" required>
<input type="button" value="GO" id="goButton" class="gosubmit"  onclick="checkLoginPass()" />
```

Javascript

```
function inputFocus(i) {
    if (i.value == i.defaultValue) { i.value = ""; i.style.color = "#000"; }
}
function inputBlur(i) {
    if (i.value == "") { i.value = i.defaultValue; i.style.color = "#888"; }
}
var checkLoginPass = function () {
    var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (login === "Client1" && pass === "Client1") {
        window.location.replace("/Design1/index.html");
    }
    else {
        //do something else;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple forms with the same IDs. Give a unique ID to every form (and input field) you have.

Comment: @KaarelNummert ok so my problem is that I have no id for the form and when I add one it has to be unique?

Comment: Not just forms, All elements must have unique id's or no id's. You have multiple inputs with the same id. You really shouldn't be using id's at all for this form since it isn't unique in any way.

Comment: Why would you need 20 login forms?

Comment: Also, this type of login form is very insecure. It is extremely easy to hack them as the password is stored in the script.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickEvans, I'm not sure why you would need 20 login forms, but regardless they will definitely need unique IDs in order to be referenced separately.

Comment: I just thought this would be quicker and simpler for me than trying to work out how to do one login form that redirects to 20 different pages when a user logs in

Comment: Why don't you use HTTP Basic Authentication then?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I am not sure what that means I am new to all of this but I will go and do some research :) If you could enlighten me that would be good too :)

Comment: Why not just do user, pw, then a drop down saying bring me to this page after log in. then write backend code that redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said this storing username and password combos in your JavaScript source is a bad idea.  But I'd like to show you how you can use arrays to store `Key -> Value` pairs and reference them to reduce the amount of code duplication.

---

In JavaScript you can define an array like so:

```
var _CONFIG = {
    "Client1": {
        "Password": "Client1",
        "Redirect": "/Design1/index.html"
    },
    "Client2": {
        "Password": "Client2",
        "Redirect": "/Design2/index.html"
    }
};
```

^ In this example your `username` is the Key and the Value is another array containing your `password` and a path to redirect to.

You can then rewrite your function to check if a Key is present in the array by using `_CONFIG[login] !== undefined`, in this case `login` is a variable containing the Key you want to look up.  Then use the array stored under that Key to provide some Values to use in your code.

```
function checkLoginPass() {
    var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ( _CONFIG[login] !== undefined && _CONFIG[login]["Password"] == pass) {
        window.location.replace(_CONFIG[login]["Redirect"]);
    }
    else {
        //do something else;
    }
}
```

^ Here is your login checking function rewritten to use the array I defined.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rMvVJ/)

---

As I said at the beginning I don't suggest that you actually use this example as it's extremely simple for someone to bypass.
Instead logins should be dealt with using a Server Side scripting technology (e.g PHP) or using the built in `HTTP Basic Authentication` as suggested to you in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is that in your javascript, you're only checking the values of the first set of fields. This will always be the case as long as you're doing it this way. And as others have said in their comments, having the passwords just sitting there in plaintext in the javascript is *incredibly* insecure, as anyone can just look at the js source code, identify username/password combinations, and log in.

The correct way to handle user logins is to have a single form with username and password, and then to pass those fields to the server via standard form submission. i.e. (incredibly simplified for brevity):

```
<form method='post' action='handlelogin.php'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br />
    Password: <input type='password' name='password' id='password' /><br />
    <input type='submit' value='Log In' onclick="return [some function that verifies both fields have been entered]()" />
</form>
```

You then validate the username/password combinations on the server, within `handlelogin.php` and ideally based on database values, and from there you redirect the user based on their credentials. If the user/pass are invalid, you send them back to the login page and display an appropriate error. If the credentials are valid, you set a cookie with an encrypted value to indicate that they're logged in and as whom, and then put them where they need to go.

Having 20 different login forms that are all validated in client-side javascript might actually be the worst way to handle user login ever conceived. Don't do that.

Comment: Haha! Thanks for the advice, I have looked for a tutorial with no joy, do you know of any tutorials for this?

Comment: is there any way I can stay as I am doing it this simple way but redirect the person after login using their username. I.e username: hamster1 redirects to hamster1.html?